# Is it possible to access the building textures from the Google Earth API?

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-api

I'm trying to get building textures from Google Earth and apply them to my own models. My overall goal is to be able to walk around in virtual reality.

So far, I've found some information from the samples provided by google. In one example, the textures are held in texture folder.

http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/resources/textures/

I doubt it's this simple, I imagine you need to either use KML or call Google Earth's LAYER_BUILDINGS.